# Make Eclipse recognize the difference between normal source files and test source files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testing, dependencies

I'm using [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) 4.3.1 with Maven Integration.

Eclipse doesn't recognize the difference between normal source files and test source files.

For example: When I use a class of Mockito which's scope is test in the normal source folder, everything seems fine. Or when I erroneously create a class in the test source folder, nothing happens.

Only when Jenkins does the Maven build, the compile errors are shown.

Can I somehow make Eclipse work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a difference between run time and compile time.

1. **Compile time**:
   Eclipse only supports one build path per project. If your test files and your application files share the same project they share the same compile time classpath. This means you can access any classes in your src directory (test or main) and classes from any dependency. Eclipse can't mark this as error because it doesn't see a difference between all these files.
2. **Run time**:
   Eclipse allows different classpaths at runtime and m2e supports this. Every forbidden access results in a RuntimeException (ClassNotFoundException).

Access at runtime is as follows:

```
# access from -> access to
src/main/java -> jar(scope: compile) [allowed]
src/main/java -> jar(scope: test)    [forbidden]
src/main/java -> src/test/java       [forbidden]

src/test/java -> jar(scope: compile) [allowed]
src/test/java -> jar(scope: test)    [allowed]
src/test/java -> src/main/java       [allowed]
```

To answer your question: What you want is not possible without patching eclipse.
Although you could split your test files and your application into separate projects.

The simplest solution is to run/test your application on your local machine before checking in.

Comment: Just to clarify, @Absurd-Mind suggests to run "mvn test" locally before checking in--you can do so with your maven/eclipse integration right from within eclipse (or, also from the command line in the directory with your pom.xml). I think it's good advice!

Comment: @user2317875 "mvn test" does not help at all. You have to run the main application. It suffices to start the application from Eclipse. (mvn test before checking in is still good advice)

Comment: You are correct! I had it backwards there and commented after reading your last sentence about run/test your application locally. My error--thanks!

Comment: Thinking about this some more, wouldn't mvn test actually expose the problem, @Absurd-Mind? Since it falls after mvn compile in the default lifecycle, the compile step would fail. So, back to thinking it's just plain good advice to run mvn test before checking in changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Absurd-Mind. Is there an IDE that knows the difference at compile time?

Comment: sorry, i'm only using eclipse